# vxml goto new document while prompts in queue

Tags: vxml

I have 2 vxml documents as below:

```
<vxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml" version="2.0">

  <catch event="error.badfetch">
    <prompt> Error in fetching document. end of test</prompt>
    <exit />
  </catch>

  <catch event="error.connection.baddestination">
    <prompt> Error 600. End of test</prompt>
    <exit />
  </catch>

  <form id="main_menu">

    <property name="confidencelevel" value="0.1" />

    <field name="menu_choice" type="digits?maxlength=1">
      <prompt>
        <break time="1s" />
        Enter a number
      </prompt>

      <filled>
        <prompt>
          <break time="1.5s" />
          This is not Google voice
          <break time="2s" />
        </prompt>
        <goto next="doc2.vxml" />
      </filled>
    </field>

  </form>
</vxml>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<vxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml" version="2.0">

  <form id="main">
    <property name="ttsengine" expr="'google-tts'" />

    <block>
      <log>Google TTS test</log>
    </block>
    <field name="menu_choice" type="digits?maxlength=1">
      <prompt>This is Google voice</prompt>

      <filled>
        <goto next="doc1.vxml" />
      </filled>
    </field>
  </form>
</vxml>
```

My question:
In doc1.vxml, "This is not Google voice" was queued ( not played), when ttsengine was set to mrcp. In doc2.vxml, ttsengine was set to google. Then the 2 prompts: "This is not Google voice" and "This is Google voice" were played at the same time using google engine. Is this correct or should the 1 be played using mrcp, the 2nd using google?

Comment: This is pretty much how the "goto" node for a new document should be processed.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the [VoiceXML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/) doesn't prescribe any specific behaviour.

My expectation would be that the VoiceXML interpreter should queue the first prompt with everything that is relevant to generate the same output as if it would be played where it is queued, including any non-standard properties affecting the generated output, like the `ttsengine` property. Unfortunately, the VoiceXML standard doesn't acknowledge this notion of *generation* step.  It's only *queued* or *played*, leaving unspecified the actual moment when the prompt is generated. The `audiofetchhint` property influences when the VoiceXML platform actually fetch the audio files but there is no equivalent for speech synthesis.

If you add a `fetchaudio` on the `goto` element, the prompt queue should be *flushed* (and thus *generated*) on the first document. Note that this is not necessarily the right work-around if you want this prompt to be played with barge-in enabled in the second question.

From the spec:

> While in the transitioning state various prompts are queued, either by
>   the  element in executable content or by the `<prompt>` element
>   in form items. In addition, audio may be queued by the fetchaudio
>   attribute. The queued prompts and audio are played either
>
> - when the interpreter reaches the waiting state, at which point the
>     prompts are played and the interpreter listens for input that matches
>     one of the active grammars, or
> - when the interpreter begins fetching a
>     resource (such as a document) for which `fetchaudio` was specified. In
>     this case the prompts queued before the `fetchaudio` are played to
>     completion, and then, if the resource actually needs to be fetched
>     (i.e. it is not unexpired in the cache), the `fetchaudio` is played
>     until the fetch completes. The interpreter remains in the
>     transitioning state and no input is accepted during the fetch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very complete. As per required by QA I have changed our implementation such as the doc1 uses mrcp & the 2nd uses google ttsengine

Answer (score 0):

You need to return control to the user for the prompt buffer to flush before you go to the next document .

To make the above work add a simple menu before the goto .

Pseudo Something like :

```
menu collect digits 
play digits voice one
menu press 1 to hear the same in another voice
goto voice two
play digits voice two
```